# After load the body with ajax load in codeigniter frame work category id is not found

Tags: php, ajax

I just tried to load the specific category page by category id with jquery ajax. I load the pages with ajax load function. It show the pages but after ajax load codeigniter notice me that the id is undefined. Please help me.

Here is my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function loadContent(url) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: 5
            },
            cache: false,

            success: function(data) {
                alert(url + id);
                $('body').load(url + id);


            }
        });
    }

    $('.links a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var URL = $(this).attr('href');
        var url = baseURL + 'Category/category_show/';

        history.pushState(null, null, URL);
        loadContent(url);
    });
});
```

---

Here is my controller:

```
public function category_show() 
{

     $id = $_POST['id'];
     echo $id;
     $data = array();
     $data['category_wise_product'] = $this - > Category_Model - > getCategoryProduct($id);
     $data['page_content'] = $this - > load - > view('site/pages/category', $data, true);
     $this - > load - > view('site/homepage', $data);
 }
```

Comment: `id` is undefined because there is only one parameter which is `url` in `loadContent(url)`. That's why `id` is undefined

Comment: Hi, I just send the static id as data  id:5 just next to the method.  So, I did not send id parameter.

Answer (score -1):

It will work when you use `html()` instead of `load()`.

`.load` is a shorthand for doing an asynchronous request and putting the contents in the element you are calling this on.

`.html` is a method to put the argument to it as the contents of the element you are calling this on.